# Inferno.js and React Semantic UI Toolkit Compatibility

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, infernojs

I'm working through a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etq_vv_RVcU&list=PLN3n1USn4xlnulnnBGD2RMid_p7xVj9xU&index=2) today, but trying to substitute Inferno since it will be good practice if we go with Inferno for a new web app I'm building (since I'm not allowed to use React - it's complicated).

In the tut, I was introduced to the [React Semantic UI toolkit](http://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/breadcrumb), which looks pretty useful, but it has peer dependencies to React and react-dom.

So my general question/issue is "how can I (or is it possible) to resolve these types of things that won't build because it says react is required?"

Comment: use [inferno-compat](https://github.com/infernojs/inferno/tree/master/packages/inferno-compat)

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that, but the docs weren't clear on what exactly to use that for (to me at least; I'm sure veteran web developers understood it fine).